# How to add Date elements to array within a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date

Sorry I'm a beginner and I'm really stuck. I want the following code to PUSH the following dates for me into an array:
Jan 01 2017
Mar 31 2017
Apr 01 2017
Jun 30 2017
Jul 01 2017
Sep 30 2017
Oct 01 2017
Dec 31 2017

... etc. Which is correctly coming out of the console.log(s). That's why I'm trying use dates.push(s) to save them in an array. However, it's saving incorrectly; when I print dates[], the array is filled only with "January 1 2022". I can't figure out why

```
    var s = startDate;
var dates = [];

while (s < today) {
    console.log(s);
    dates.push(s);
 
    s.setMonth(s.getMonth() + 3);
    s.setDate(s.getDate() - 1);

    dates.push(s);
    
    console.log(s);
    
    s.setDate(s.getDate() + 1);
    

}


dates.forEach(function(dates) {
  console.log(dates);

  //this just returns January 1, 2022 over and over
});
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Clarifying: startDate = January 1 2017

Comment: There's only one "date" -> `s`. Your script pushes references to that one "date" into `dates` ([Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)). In the end you will have a bunch of pointers (references) that all point to that one "date"

Comment: Thank you! It's hard to understand but very important

Comment: You need a new `Date` instance in every round of the `while` loop

Comment: Or you can push strings: `dates.push(s.toString());`. :-)